# Using IBM JVM with Python and Java

Tags: ibm-midrange, aix

I am trying to use the IBM JVM on my I series (AIX PASE) box to create Python and JAVA programs to be able to connect to Oracle and Mysql databases. The goal is to move away from RPG programming to either Python or Java, but I am unable to find any documentation on IBM JVM , JDBC drivers setup and identify shared libraries that might be needed for the JVM to start from third party python modules. We re currently using AIX V7R4.

Comment: Java and Python are different things; if interested in Java, search google for `jdbc oracle`

Comment: Agree Lorinczy, so what i am attempting is a JDBC thin driver connection from Python using one of the libraries which needs to start JVM on IBM I machine but its running into a crash.

Comment: Afaik, jdbc can only be used from Java. For other languages use the actual Oracle Client. (Which can be the InstantClient.) Also this component for Python3: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#quick-start-cx-oracle-installation